# Realm, Save json with multiple objects and arrays

Tags: android, json, realm

I am new to realm, I achieved saving data with simple json but now i have a json with multiple objects and arrays and i have spend huge time trying achieve this. Any help will be appreciated.

The sample json is below:

```
    {
"status": 200,
"message": "Success",
"data": [
{
"containerStatus2": "Loaded",
"stops": [
{
"city": "ADDSTOPCITY",
"id": "70"
}
],
"containerStatus": "Loaded",
"instructions": "testing load",
"dispatcher": {
"status": 0,
"image_url": "https://lorempixel.com/200/200/technics/6",
"os": ""
},
"docs": [
{
"link": "https://alfred.urbantrucking.com/static/uploads/hhzgkplbqdec.jpg",
"type": "POD",
"name": "marijuana-map-large.jpg"
},
{
"type": "BOL",
"link": "https://alfred.urbantrucking.com/static/uploads/jttojntemolt.jpg",
"name": "lab-test.jpg"
}
],
"created": "Jan-01-2018, 09:36 PM",
"pods": [],
"container2": ""
}],
"success": 1
}
```

Comment: Parse it into some random POJO then map it over into a RealmObject.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

```
-----------------------------------com.example.Datum.java-----------------------------------


public class Datum extends RealmObject{

    private String containerStatus2;
    private List<Stop> stops = null;
    private String containerStatus;
    private String instructions;
    private Dispatcher dispatcher;
    private List<Doc> docs = null;
    private String created;
    private List<Object> pods = null;
    private String container2;

    public String getContainerStatus2() {
        return containerStatus2;
    }

    public void setContainerStatus2(String containerStatus2) {
        this.containerStatus2 = containerStatus2;
    }

    public List<Stop> getStops() {
        return stops;
    }

    public void setStops(List<Stop> stops) {
        this.stops = stops;
    }

    public String getContainerStatus() {
        return containerStatus;
    }

    public void setContainerStatus(String containerStatus) {
        this.containerStatus = containerStatus;
    }

    public String getInstructions() {
        return instructions;
    }

    public void setInstructions(String instructions) {
        this.instructions = instructions;
    }

    public Dispatcher getDispatcher() {
        return dispatcher;
    }

    public void setDispatcher(Dispatcher dispatcher) {
        this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
    }

    public List<Doc> getDocs() {
        return docs;
    }

    public void setDocs(List<Doc> docs) {
        this.docs = docs;
    }

    public String getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(String created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public List<Object> getPods() {
        return pods;
    }

    public void setPods(List<Object> pods) {
        this.pods = pods;
    }

    public String getContainer2() {
        return container2;
    }

    public void setContainer2(String container2) {
        this.container2 = container2;
    }

}
```

-----------------------------------com.example.Dispatcher.java-----------------------------------

```
public class Dispatcher extends RealmObject{

    private int status;
    private String imageUrl;
    private String os;

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getOs() {
        return os;
    }

    public void setOs(String os) {
        this.os = os;
    }

}
```

-----------------------------------com.example.Doc.java-----------------------------------

```
public class Doc extends RealmObject{

    private String link;
    private String type;
    private String name;

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

-----------------------------------com.example.Response.java-----------------------------------

```
public class Response extends RealmObject {

    private int status;
    private String message;
    private List<Datum> data = null;
    private int success;

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public List<Datum> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(int success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

}
```

-----------------------------------com.example.Stop.java-----------------------------------

```
public class Stop extends RealmObject{

    private String city;
    private String id;

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/

and save:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(this);
realm.beginTransaction();
Response u = realm.createObject(Response.class);
u.setMessage("Hello response");
realm.commitTransaction();
```